# Finding Bluetooth Mac address in Windows10 UWP without pairing

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10

I'm trying to write an app that reads all MAC addresses around on Windows 10 IoT. These lines of code is returning all paired devices even if they aren't turn on.

```
var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
listBox.Items.Add(devices.Count);
foreach (var device in devices)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(device.Id);
}
```

And I also found this line of code

```
await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

This returning null though.  Is there any way to scan for all MAC addresses in a Windows 10 universal app?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to finding the answer of your question.  You might try getting a `BluetoothDevice` instance from the DeviceId property. You will then be able to get all the specific Bluetooth information including the Bluetooth address

```
var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
foreach (var device in devices)
{
    var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
    if (bluetoothDevice != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(bluetoothDevice.BluetoothAddress);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(device.Id);
    foreach(var property in device.Properties)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("   " + property.Key + " " + property.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The App still founding only devices that are already paired. Is there any way to find MAC adress without pairing?

Comment: No, you actually can't do that.

Comment: ok, so how can i find paired devices but only those which are in range of devices. Becouse this lines of code founding all devices that were ever paired.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new approach using [BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher.aspx) to scan for all Bluetooth LE device around.
Here is a piece of code I use in my project:

```
var advertisementWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher()
{
    SignalStrengthFilter.InRangeThresholdInDBm = -100,
    SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -102,
    SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)
};

advertisementWatcher.Received += AdvertisementWatcher_Received;
advertisementWatcher.Stopped += AdvertisementWatcher_Stopped;

advertisementWatcher.Start();
```

and later

```
advertisementWatcher.Stop();

advertisementWatcher.Received -= AdvertisementWatcher_Received;
advertisementWatcher.Stopped -= AdvertisementWatcher_Stopped;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //MessAgeChanged(MsgType.NotifyTxt, "FR_NAME:"+ eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName + "BT_ADDR: " + eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
        string sDevicename = setup.Default.BLEName.Text;
        BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress).Completed = async (asyncInfo, asyncStatus) =>
        {
            if (asyncStatus == AsyncStatus.Completed)
            {
                if (asyncInfo.GetResults() == null)
                {
                    if (!FailMsg)
                    {
                        MessAgeChanged(MsgType.NotifyTxt, "None");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    BluetoothLEDevice currentDevice = asyncInfo.GetResults();

                    Boolean contain = false;
                    foreach (BluetoothLEDevice device in DeviceList.ToArray())/
                    {
                        if (device.DeviceId == currentDevice.DeviceId)
                        {
                            contain = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!contain)
                    {
                        byte[] _Bytes1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(currentDevice.BluetoothAddress);
                        Array.Reverse(_Bytes1);
                        // The received signal strength indicator (RSSI)
                        double rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm;
                        DeviceList.Add(currentDevice);
                            MessAgeChanged(MsgType.NotifyTxt, currentDevice.Name + "        " + BitConverter.ToString(_Bytes1, 2, 6).Replace('-', ':').ToLower() + "           " + rssi);
                            DeviceWatcherChanged(MsgType.BleDevice, currentDevice);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```